# Are there exotic type of loss functions used in supervised learning?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, loss-functions

Almost every loss function I've ever seen are either

1. Euclidean norm
2. Cross entropy (sum of weighted logs)
3. Hinge loss (for SVM, or perceptron)

Are there any exotic type of distances that are used in supervised learning?

Comment: Maybe quantile loss? What qualifies as an exotic loss? Brandon Rohrer discusses loss functions in one of his YouTube videos, I think the long one on convolutional neural networks.

Comment: @Dave: I would assume that the hinge loss is the quantile loss.

Comment: @Dave You raise an interesting point, but the loss for CNN is usually the cross entropy since by stacking linear layers on top of conv layers, you effectively get a softmax regression

Comment: @StephanKolassa, the two do not seem to be the same; see e.g. ["Most Common Loss Functions in Machine Learning"](https://towardsdatascience.com/most-common-loss-functions-in-machine-learning-c7212a99dae0).

Comment: @Cauchy'sCarrot CNNs often get used for classification problems with crossentropy as the loss, but a convolutional neural network architecture could be used for regression or quantile regression. It depends on the problem inputs, outputs, and goal.

Answer (score 2):

In the field of image segmentation, there is also the dice-loss (derived from F1-score) and the Jaccard loss (derived from Jaccard index).

Both are described in this article:

https://towardsdatascience.com/image-segmentation-choosing-the-correct-metric-aa21fd5751af

The field of (supervised) metric-learning has some different loss functions, too. See triplet-loss for example.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure wuaht you mean by "exotic" but two others I have encountered occaisionally are:

- Huber loss funtion. This is similar to mean squared error but the errors are squared only inside an interval, and so it is more "robust" to outliers, and thus is sometimes used with very noisy data.
- Kullback-Leibler divergence. This is sometimes called Relative Entropy, and measures the divergence of one probability distribution from another and is often used in multiclass classification problems.

Comment: Any examples on which types of supervised learning problems these are used for?

Comment: @RichardHardy I've updated the answer with use cases.

Comment: Thank you. What machine learning methods (like neural networks, SVMs, ...) that apply Huber loss and KL divergence have you encountered the most?

Comment: @RichardHardy for KL that would definitely be autoencoders, but that's not supervised learning, so I didn't mention it. I've seen Huber loss used mostly with regression problems.